# Dimmer switches & LED lights: Lights keep turning up to max and won't stay dim

Tags: lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I'm a tenant in an apartment and we're having strange lighting issues. We have a dimmable light switch panel in our lounge with 2 controls, controlling 4 LED spotlights each.

The dimmers make a buzzing sound when you turn it and hit either the minimum or maximum bounds, which is normal. If we turn it on and set it to the dimmest setting, after a while (could be a couple of minutes, could be 15 minutes), the lights automatically start getting brighter and brighter, and the light switch starts buzzing every 10/20 seconds. I assume the buzzing is because it's hit it's max range and something is trying to keep increasing it.

If we then turn it down again to the dimmest setting, it will eventually (could be a few minutes, could be 30 mins later) do the same thing. So we're basically unable to have our lights on dim!

We've had the light dimmer switch completely replaced the other day but it's just started happening again.

The electrician seems stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: could you give us more on the type of dimmer, I have observed the digital dimmers crosstalking (a control on a different circuit taking control) but this sounds different,

Comment: Who installed the LED spots?  Not all LED replacement bulbs are dimmable and can cause a variety of issues with a dimmer switch.

Comment: It's a new-build property, so I'm sure everything is okay in that respect.

Comment: Yes it does sound a little different as no other switches are being touched when this happens. It's very intermittent though. Regarding type of dimmer, if you'd like model info I don't think I can find it because it's just a plain metal light switch with no info on.

Comment: If the fixture was designed for LEDs and came from the factory with them installed, it's probably OK (could still contain a non-dimmable transformer), but based on the issues you are having, I'd try some regular bulbs (if possible) with the fixture and see if you have problems.

Comment: Related PDF from Lutron: [Minimum and Maximum loads for LED and CFL lamps](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/048487.pdf).  In the past, the minimum for a dimmer didn't matter because even a single 25w bulb was enough, but with modern LEDs it can be a problem.

Comment: I don't really understand why this isn't being dealt with by your landlord. Part of your rent goes to maintenance. This is maintenance. Get them to get a better electrician.

Comment: The issue is being dealt with the landlord, but it's just a bit slow! Also, as the electrician was confused I thought I'd do my own research so I could perhaps point them in the right direction. Plus, I'm just very curious!

Comment: sorry  - just trying to catch my breath from laughing so hard... that was an awesome joke.  everythings fine because its a new build !  that is sooooo funny.  you should be a comic.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous poster to experiment with different bulbs. I have a different circumstance (older dimmer switch with track lighting) but the symptoms were similar for me. I was hearing a maddening low hum unless on full blast. I found that LEDs labeled as dimmable or regular incandescents work fine. It was an off brand LED that finally worked. Also consider that newly built does not always = correctly built.